# Is there a way to show action buttons on all devices including ones with menu button?

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-appcompat

The question says it all.  But I want a search button to be in the top right of the screen on all devices.  I know that if there is a hardware menu button that the action buttons will be in a popup menu at the bottom but I don't want that.  I need the buttons on the actionbar.  Preferably not the overflow button workaround either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Karakuri's Answer is very close but I will make my own to clarify.

The key is define the xml schema in the menu tag under your namespace along with the android schema.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
```

And then in the item, it needs to be

```
yourapp:showAsAction="always"
```

not

```
android:showAsAction="always"
```

this is where I messed up.

It shows it in the docs but I accidentally skipped over it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ActionBarSherlock or the new v7 support library to support ActionBar on older devices, including ones with hardware menu key. Make your search menu item have `android:showAsAction="always"`

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. Maybe I typed it wrong or something.

Comment: Is there anything special you have to do? I added that line to my menu item but still on the bottom and not in the actionbar